# Is there a Java equivalent to if __FILE__ == $0?

Tags: java, ruby, equivalent

I know that in Python and Ruby there are the snippets `if __name__ == '__main__':`
 and `if __FILE__ == $0`, which would run only run if the script was opened directly.

This seems like a really useful feature that I haven't seen in Java (my school's "official" programming language). Is there any equivalent to this in Java? If not, is there any way to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

java has the `public static void main(String[] args)` method.  this is invoked when a class is run as the main class from the command line, and generally *only* invoked in such a scenario (you could call it directly, but it usually doesn't make sense).  so, in java, the standard is to put "main invocation" logic in this method.

Comment: The `main` function isn't invoked merely by including the class as a library in your project. If you wanted to run `main` for a library, you'd have to go out of your way to explicitly call it.

Answer (score 5):

To add to [jthalborn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696752/is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-if-file-0/5696866#5696866):

The real question isn't "how do I do this in Java?" it's "why do Ruby and Python need such a kludge?"

The answer is that Ruby and Python expect to execute a file from start to finish when the file is loaded (either as a library or as the main program), so you need a hack to say "don't run this part if I'm being called as a library". Java has no expectation of running a file or class from start to finish. It has a `main()` in a particular class which contains code for when that class is being used as the main program. Therefore, Java doesn't need this hack.

(C and C++ are like Java in this regard, but you can only have one `main()` function in a program, so you either need to resort to using the preprocessor to decide which one to compile in, or you need to put different `main()` functions in different files, and compile in only the files that you need.)

Comment: I don't want to downvote this for the "kludge" / "hack" comment, but this is just wrong. It's a design decision and effectively "executing" a library on inclusion gives you interesting possibilities (you know the exact order / moment of module's initialisation). One could just as well call Java's model a hack, because you have to have the used API available during the compilation. Different approach != kludge.

Answer (score 0):

Get a stacktrace and have a look at the first method:

```
Throwable t = new Throwable();
StackTraceElement[] elems = t.getStackTrace();
... elems[elems.length-1] should contain a main method ... check if it is yours :) ...
```

Comment: in other words, just add a static method named `main` to the class in whatever file you're working on.

Comment: This works only if you don't start any separate threads, though.